# Exchange Online ESMTP responds differently from different clients - Windows 10 vs Windows Server 2019

Tags: firewall, smtp, microsoft-office-365, exchangeonline, watchguard

When I telnet to our Exchange Online's SMTP server address (`****.mail.protection.outlook.com`, `port 25`) I get two different responses or types of connect depending on what machine I'm using.

When I connect using my desktop (Windows 10) I get what I expect - I can use the full set of commands, and EHLO gives a full output, including the correct SIZE (150MB).

When I connect from a Windows Server 2019 VM it says a lot of syntax is missing (HELP doesn't work, EHLO requires me to supply out domain name) and the EHLO response is truncated and the SIZE is wrong - 20MB instead of 150MB.

Windows 10 Telnet Results:
[image: Windows 10 Telnet Results]

Server 2019 Telnet Results:
[image: Server 2019 Telnet Results]

This appears to be related to an error we're getting sending larger attachments to 365 from the server that works sending from my computer.

Both the 2019 VM and my computer are on the same network, the same firewall rules apply to both.  I tried another Windows Server 2019 VM and it behaves the same was, getting the "wrong" results.

This is a weird one to me, any suggestions for what's going?

Comment: "This appears to be related to an error we're getting sending larger attachments to 365 from the server that works sending from my computer."
Perhaps the 365 server triggered the throttling.Try sending with the same attach as the win10.

Comment: That's what I did to test - it sends successfully from the Windows 10 machine.  I just don't know why or where in 365 to tell it to allow it.

Answer (score 0):

Mystery solved!  Our Watchguard firewall is set to inspect (and intercept) traffic from the 2019 servers but not from my Windows 10 workstation.  I had initially been told this was not involved.  Watchguard ESMTP and SMTP settings can be configured according to this article:

https://www.watchguard.com/help/docs/help-center/en-US/Content/en-US/Fireware/proxies/smtp/proxy_smtp_gen_settings_c.html